# Deploying Flask app with Gunicorn and Nginx on CentOS7 results in 502 Error

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn, centos7

I am trying to deploy a flask application called *pytimesheets* on a CentOS7 VM using Gunicorn and Nginx. I was basically following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-7) with some minor changes.

When I start the application with `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 wsgi:app` (without using Nginx) it works, but that's not the way I want it to run.

So I created a **systemd service unit file** /etc/systemd/system/pytimesheets.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve pytimesheets
After=network.target

[Service]
User=centos
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/centos/pytimesheets/pytimesheets
Environment="PATH=/home/centos/miniconda/envs/pytimesheets-dev/bin"
ExecStart=/home/centos/miniconda/envs/pytimesheets-dev/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:pytimesheets.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=mulit-user.target
```

Started and enabled the gunicorn service - worked!

Next, I configured **Nginx**:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name my.servername.com;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/centos/pytimesheets/pytimesheets/pytimesheets.sock;
        }
    }


    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

I added the user nginx to my usergroup (centos, has sudo privileges) `sudo usermod -a -G user nginx` and gave it execute permissions in my home directory `chmod 710 /home/centos`

Finally, I started nginx, but all I get when I visit the site is a **502 Bad Gateway Error.**

The Nginx error log shows me this:

```
2016/07/06 13:33:44 [crit] 17464#0: 
*1 connect() to unix:/home/centos/pytimesheets/pytimesheets/pytimesheets.sock 
failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, 
client: 10.250.16.87, server: my.servername.com, 
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://unix:/home/centos/pytimesheets/pytimesheets/pytimesheets.sock:/", 
host: "my.servername.com"
```

The sock file is created once I start the pytimesheets service, and the location `/home/centos/pytimesheets/pytimesheets/pytimesheets.sock` may look weird, but it's correct.

My guess is that there is something messed up with the user rights.
Does anybody have an idea what I did wrong?

**Update**

I was able to run the application after setting `setenforce = Permissive`. However, I don't know if this is a permament solution.

Comment: gunicorn creates the file with 007, so only the user centos should be able to access it. nginx runs as user nginx so it can't acces the 007 file. Does changing the gunicorn execution to `gunicorn [...] -m 077` work?

Comment: Nope, still the same error. What is weird is, that I see the sock file, but I cannot access it. E.g. `cat pytimesheets.sock` returns `cat: pytimesheets.sock: No such device or address` and if I try to open it with `vim pytimesheets.sock` I get `[Permission Denied]` in vim. I tried this as both centos and root.

Comment: What permission does something like `ls -la` (or `stat` or whatever) show on that file?

Comment: `ls -la` shows `s-wxrw-rw-. 1 centos nginx 0 Jul  7 09:31 pytimesheets.sock`

Comment: maybe it help`s you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799746/nginx-permission-denied-to-gunicorn-socket-on-centos-7