# Nginx: Permission denied to Gunicorn socket on CentOS 7

Tags: django, nginx, centos7, gunicorn

I'm working in a Django project deployment. I'm working in a CentOS 7 server provided ma EC2 (AWS). I have tried to fix this bug by many ways but I cant understand what am I missing.

I'm using ningx and gunicorn to deploy my project. I have created my `/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service`file with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=centos
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/centos/myproject_app
ExecStart=/home/centos/myproject_app/django_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/centos/myproject_app/django.sock app.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run `sudo systemctl restart myproject.service`and `sudo systemctl enable myproject.service`, the `django.sock` file is correctly generated into `/home/centos/myproject_app/`.

I have created my `nginx` conf flie in the folder /etc/nginx/sites-available/ with the following content:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  my_ip;
    charset      utf-8;

    client_max_body_size       10m;
    client_body_buffer_size    128k;

    # serve static files
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/centos/myproject_app/app/static/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/centos/myproject_app/django.sock;
    }
}
```

After, I restart `nginx` with the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

If I run the command `sudo nginx -t`, the reponse is:

```
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

When I visit my_ip in a web browser, I'm getting a 502 bad gateway response.

If I check the nginx error log, I see the following message:

```
1 connect() to unix:/home/centos/myproject_app/django.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream
```

I really have tried a lot of solutions changing the sock file permissions. But I cant understand how to fix it. How can I fix this permissions bug?... Thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried running in `DEBUG`? Also, what does your `gunicorn` log say?

Comment: try `$ journalctl gunicorn` to see the logs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If all the permissions under the `myproject_app` folder are correct, and `centos` user or `nginx` group have access to the files, I would say it looks like a Security Enhanced Linux (SELinux) issue.

I had a similar problem, but with RHEL 7. I managed to solve it by executing the following command:

```
sudo semanage permissive -a httpd_t
```

It's related to the security policies of SELinux, you have to add the `httpd_t` to the list of permissive domains.

This post from the NGINX blog may be helpful: [NGINX: SELinux Changes when Upgrading to RHEL 6.6 / CentOS 6.6](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-se-linux-changes-upgrading-rhel-6-6/)

Motivated by a similar issue, I wrote a tutorial a while ago on [How to Deploy a Django Application on RHEL 7](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/05/23/how-to-deploy-a-django-application-on-rhel.html). It should be very similar for CentOS 7.

Comment: After several searches, this answer solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Most probably one of two

1- the directory is not accessible to nginx `/home/centos/myproject_app/`

```
$ ls -la /home/centos/myproject_app/
```

if it is not accessible try to change the path to `/etc/nginx`
if not then try the command

```
$ /home/centos/myproject_app/django_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/centos/myproject_app/django.sock app.wsgi:application
```

if still not working then activate the environment and `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` go to the browser and go to http://ip:8000 the problem may be here, but it the command of gunicorn worked well, then the problem in directory access for nginx user

Comment: Moving the socket to /tmp fixed it for me. Not sure why.

Comment: Because it's accessable to the webserver

Answer (score -2):

Exact same problem here.

Removing `Group=www-data` fixed the issue for me